# MaterialTapTargetPrompt: Way to have skip button to skip tutorial

Tags: android

I have a tutorial demo app from here https://github.com/sjwall/MaterialTapTargetPrompt and I've successfully implemented it for my app. but is there a way to have a skip button on the prompt to skip that tutorial?
I was just wondering if someone here found a way to do that I'd really appreciate some help.
[image]